# How do i display side by side in console c#

Tags: c#

What: I am trying to print game stats side to side as a UI enhancement

My thought so far is to put in in a 2 dimensional array and print side to side as so. 
I want to know if there is another easier way or am i on the right track.

Comment: Dude, *show us what you've tried* for the love of god.  Sigh...

Comment: Maybe he wants to know if there is a way built in before he wastes his time coding it?  Having said that Olay, I don't know what you mean with your idea

Comment: are you talking like player 1 stats side by side next to player 2?

Comment: Well its a task I haven't gotten too yet just trying to plan on how I'd do it. not asking for code just a conceptual idea of it. I know i can do it using a 2 dimensional array and just printing it like that. I was just asking if there are other ways

Comment: Yes Alex that's exactly what I mean

Comment: what is your GUI now, a winform, wpf, website??

Comment: @Olay, does this help? (see the example too)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Console Application

Comment: Thanks matt, I like that the idea behind that definitely giving that a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it by using `Console.SetCursorPosition` to just print text to any position on the screen.

See this link for an example:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would just keep the stats (whether they be arrays/lists or whatever) within each of the player classes and then output Player1.stats, Player2.stats, etc. Seems a bit clearer that way.